# How to delay a javascript from loading

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript that takes AGES to load and slows the website down on load so bad, like 5 seconds to load! I was wondering if I could make the JavaScript load after the website has loaded, so the Javascript doesnt slow the site down on load?

Comment: Just place it at the bottom, right before `</body>`, or use `defer` or async loading.

Comment: I have got the code at the bottom, however it still takes a bitch to load

Comment: @user2985228, but everything downloads but the JavaScript first. That is what you wanted, right?

Comment: Something is wrong with your site if it takes 5 seconds for javascipt to load.

Answer (score 0):

Try including your file after the page loads,

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    var elem = document.createElement('script');
    elem.type = 'text/javascript';
    elem.src = 'yourfile.js';
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
},false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest method that is widely used is jQuery.

Inserting this tag in your head:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And in the bottom of the body (right before the body end)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

//// INSERT YOUR JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE /////

}); //end of document ready
</script>
</body>
</html>
```